# Why is sys+user > real in "time command"?

Tags: linux, unix, time, pthreads, benchmarking

I have a program that uses pthread library to do the matrix multiplication of 500x500 matrix. Each thread calculates 50 rows of the matrix.

When I time its execution:

```
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~$ time ./a.out

real    0m0.383s
user    0m0.810s
sys     0m0.000s
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~$
```

Why is **sys+user** is greater than **real time**?

Comment: If its relevant, I have a Core 2 Quad Processor & I have 64-bit ubuntu installed..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is greater, because it adds the time from all the cores together.